# PHP: XMLWriter producing illegal namespace declaration

Tags: php, xml, xmlwriter

XMLWriter appears broken, in that it is producing namespace declarations that
cause the instance to be not well-formed.

For example:

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openUri( 'php://output' );

$writer->startIndent( true );
$writer->setIndentString ( "\t" );
$writer->startDocument( '1.0', 'UTF-8' );

$writer->startElement( 'root' );
$writer->writeAttributeNs( 'xmlns', 'bar', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'http://example.com' );
$writer->startElementNs( 'bar', 'baz', null );
$writer->endElement();
```

produces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:bar="http://example.com" xmlns:xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">
    <bar:baz/>
</root>
```

Notice the `xmlns:xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/"`, which:

1. is nowhere in the PHP code I wrote
2. runs afoul of [Namespace constraint: Reserved Prefixes and Namespace Names](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#xmlReserved)

No matter what I do, if I create **any** namespace declarations then XMLWriter outputs this illegal namespace declaration (in addition to the namespace declarations I want it to output).

What am I missing?  Because, as is, this makes XMLWriter unusable.

**Edit:** In case it matters, I'm using PHP 5.4.16 and libxml2 2.7.8.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround: to create namespace decls, just use:

```
$writer->writeAttribute( 'xmlns:prefix', 'http://example.com' );
```

So, I suppose the problem is just the dearth of documentation on this in the PHP Manual.

BTW, the code example in my question was a simplification of the code I am actually writing, which implements a simple transformation of an instance using XMLReader & XMLWriter, ala:

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open( $file );

$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openUri( "{$file}-xformed.xml" );
$writer->setIndent( true );
$writer->setIndentString( "\t" );
$writer->startDocument( '1.0', 'UTF-8' );

while ( $reader->read() ) {
    switch ( $reader->nodeType ) {
        case XMLReader::ELEMENT:
            if ( '' === $reader->namespaceURI ) {
                $writer->startElement( $reader->localName );
            }
            else {
                $writer->startElementNS( $reader->prefix, $reader->localName, $reader->namespaceURI );
            }

            if ( $reader->hasAttributes ) {
                while ( $reader->moveToNextAttribute() ) {
                    if ( '' === $reader->namespaceURI ) {
                        $writer->writeAttribute( $reader->name, $reader->value );
                    }
                    else {
                        // this stmt was causing the illegal namespace decls
                        // even tho there is nothing wrong with the code :-(
                        $writer->writeAttributeNS( $reader->prefix, $reader->localName, $reader->namespaceURI, $reader->value );
                    }
                }
            }

            break;

        // other case stmts for other node types
    }
}
```

So, I just replaced the "attribute loop" with:

```
            if ( $reader->hasAttributes ) {
                while ( $reader->moveToNextAttribute() ) {
                    if ( in_array( $reader->namespaceURI, array( '', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ) ) {
                        // create an attribute in the empty namespace or a namespace decl
                        $writer->writeAttribute( $reader->name, $reader->value );
                    }
                    else {
                        // create a namespace-qualified attribute
                        $writer->writeAttributeNS( $reader->prefix, $reader->localName, $reader->namespaceURI, $reader->value );
                    }
                }
            }
```